# How to deserialize an html div when it has certain attributes to it?

Tags: vb.net, serialization, deserialization

For example this:

```
<div class="link_text">
 <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
 <strong>Text</strong></a>
</div>
```

With normal tags like XML ones it is easy, you just create the class with the same name as the tag, so if the tag is:

```
<something></something>
```

you create a class called something, but how would you do this in HTML in an example div such as that one, with a class attribute inside?

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the `XmlAttribute` attribute to the properties in the class to indicate that you want the property treated as an attribute instead of as an element.  For instance:

```
Public Class div
    <XmlAttribute()> _
    Public Property [class] As String
        Get
            Return _class
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _class = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _class As String

    Public Property a As a
        Get
            Return _a
        End Get
        Set(value As a)
            _a = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _a As a

    Public Property strong As String
        Get
            Return _strong
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _strong = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _strong As String
End Class

Public Class a
    <XmlAttribute()> _
    Public Property href As String
        Get
            Return _href
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _href = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _href As String
End Class
```

Normally you wouldn't need the square brackets around a property name, like there is on the `class` property.  The only reason why that's necessary in this example is because the word "Class" is a special keyword in the VB.NET language.  The brackets force VB to treat it as an identifier name instead of as the typical meaning of the keyword.  Another way to do the same thing without the brackets is to name the property something different, and then force it to have a the name "Class" in the XML:

```
Public Class div
    <XmlAttribute("class")> _
    Public Property MyClassAttribute As String
        ' ...
    End Property
End Class
```

In any case, once you deserialize it into a `div` object, you can read it like this:

```
Dim myDiv As div = '...
Dim theClassOfMyDiv As String = myDiv.class
Dim theHref As String = myDiv.a.href
' etc.
```

Comment: Mr. Doggart strikes again! By the way I messed up in the question name, it should say deserialize instead *fixed*. So what I'm looking for is how to transform the elements of that div to data I can read, as my previous questions.. :)

I'm working on this web app that will display weather forecasts, so I've been trying to gather data from all over the internet to do it.

Comment: I added a more complete example to show what I mean.  I think your larger confusion, however, may be coming from the fact that you are on the wrong track.  If your goal is to parse HTML, I wouldn't recommend XML deserialization to do it.  First of all, a lot of HTML does not meet the requirements of well-formed XML documents.  However, even if it can deserialize doesn't mean it's easy.  Attempting to build data structures to mimic an HTML document seems like an overly complicated way to go about it, especially if you are only interested in a small subset of the elements in the document.

Comment: For parsing HTML, I would strongly recommend looking into the HtmlAgility pack, which is a third-party library (free, open source, I believe).  With that, you can load the document into a standard DOM object and then easily either walk through the document tree or query data from it using XPATH.  It works very similarly to the `XmlDocument` class.

Comment: Well thanks for the heads up Steven, I'll surely look into that as soon as I can, the thing is have 2 sources, 1 is Weather Underground, I can use its API to request XML files that I do deserialize already, the other source is The Weather Channel, they do give a small peak of the kind of data I need on their site, but do not do so on their API, hence why I was attempting to try and deserialize part of the html but I guess you have more knowledge than me regarding this. I'll probably wil let you know if I have more trouble. :)

Comment: Deserialization is a very useful method to use to read XML.  It's nice because, in simple situations, it can make the code much easier to read and maintain.  However, with large complex documents, it can become difficult end up making the code less-intuitive.  It sounds like parsing the Html is reaching that level of complexity where serialization is doing more harm than good.  Once you see how easy and intuitive XPATH can be, you may even want to consider using that for both the Html and the Xml.

Comment: Plus, if the Html you are parsing is well-formed XML, as it sounds like is the case, then you don't even need the HtmlAgilityPack--you could just use `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` to parse it.

Comment: Well I guess it depends on how well-formed "well-formed" means. This is what I'm trying to read: http://espanol.weather.com/weather/hourByHour-Nueva-York-USNY0996 
The content I want is in here: <div id="table_content">

Comment: By the way, I checked on the HtmlAgilityPack and it seems to need the Visual Studio's Extension Manager, which is not available on the pre-2010 versions, I'm working on 2008. :/

Comment: Well, what I mean by well-formed is that the XmlDocument class is capable of loading it without throwing an exception.